# C# - Windows Service só executa uma vez

Tags: c#, windows, services, timer, windows-service

Estou desenvolvendo um serviço windows para executar de 10 em 10 minutos, ele insere alguns valores no banco de dados, mas notei que a rotina só é executada uma unica vez.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Teste.BLL.Servidor;
using Teste.DTO.Servidor;
using Teste.Referencia.Email;

namespace Teste.AtualizaArmazenamentoServidores
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer;
        EventLog log = new EventLog();
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();  //adicionado para conseguir deggugar no Visual Studio
            timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(timer_Tick), null, 15000, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40).Milliseconds); //coloquei 40 segundos para testar
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }

        public void timer_Tick(object sender)
        {
            ExecutarTarefa();
        }

        public void ExecutarTarefa()
        {
            try
            {
                new ServidorBLL().SalvaDadosServidoresBanco();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SendEmail("Atualiza Servico", ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

A Rotina funciona, os dados são atualizados no banco de dados certinho, mas no debug, o método não é chamado novamente após a primeira execução.

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a orientação do Renan, segue código operacional:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    EventLog log = new EventLog();
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(600000D);  
        this.timer.AutoReset = true;
        this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
        this.timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sener, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExecutarTarefa();
    }

    public void ExecutarTarefa()
    {
        //tarefa
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro ler a [documentação oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Além disso existem algumas coisas aqui que precisam ser revistas:

- O *timer* deve ser uma propriedade da classe *Service1*. Caso contrário, ele será eliminado da memória pelo Garbage Collector após a execução do método *OnStart*. Esse pode ser o principal motivo para o comportamento que o programa tem agora.
- Observe que o tipo *Timer* herda de *Idisposable*, então recomendo fortemente que implemente sua disposição também para evitar vazamenos na memória.
- Atribua à propriedade *AutoReset* da sua instância de *timer* o valor `true`. Caso contrário, mesmo segurando a instância ele ainda vai executar apenas uma vez, conforme a documentação no link.